# How to speed up loop in loop calculations in R

Tags: r, loops, overlap

Simply said I have 378742 observations (each observation has a launch and deadline date) and I want to check the overlap of the duration of each observation against all other (378741) observations and sum them up.

I am running the following code which takes forever (my estimate is that it 205 days) because of the nested loop. Is there a way to speed up the calculations? (I use `DescTools`package for the `Overlap` command.)

```
a <- c(1:378742)

for (i in 1:378742) {
  mydata$competition[i] <- sum(a, na.rm = T)
  for (j in 1:378742) {
    a[j] <- Overlap(c(mydata$Launched[i], mydata$Deadline[i]), c(mydata$Launched[j], mydata$Deadline[j]))
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverlfow! A couple of comments. Please add package that contains `Overlap` function (or is it your custom function) add example of `mydata`. Also, for sure you can move `sum(a, na.rm = TRUE)` out of the loop.

Comment: Hello, I added the package. The purpose is to measure overall overlap of each observation with all other observations. Code works perfectly but it takes days to finish. I was thinking maybe there is a way to speed up. Someone suggested AWS or H2O.ai but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save significant time by vectorizing your inner loop (I then use `apply()` for the outer loop):

```r
# We'll need both DescTools and microbenchmark
library(DescTools)
library(microbenchmark)
# Make example data
set.seed(123) # setting seed for reproducibility
n <- 10
x <- sample(seq(as.Date("2008/10/20"), as.Date("2018/10/20"), "day"), n)
y <- sample(seq(as.Date("2008/10/20"), as.Date("2018/10/20"), "day"), n)
(mat <- cbind(x, y))
#>           x     y
#>  [1,] 15222 17667
#>  [2,] 17050 15827
#>  [3,] 15665 16645
#>  [4,] 17395 16262
#>  [5,] 17603 14547
#>  [6,] 14338 17454
#>  [7,] 16098 15069
#>  [8,] 17425 14325
#>  [9,] 16181 15367
#> [10,] 15835 17650
# First get the answer using nested loops
a <- z <- 1:n
for (i in 1:n) {
    for (j in 1:n) {
        a[j] <- Overlap(mat[i, ],mat[j, ])
    }
    # Noticed I've moved this sum to the bottom,
    # so that our first element isn't just a sum from one to n
    z[i] <- sum(a, na.rm = T)
}
z
#>  [1] 16102  9561  7860  7969 18169 18140  6690 18037  6017 12374
apply(mat, 1, function(r) sum(Overlap(r, mat)))
#>  [1] 16102  9561  7860  7969 18169 18140  6690 18037  6017 12374
microbenchmark(apply = apply(mat, 1, function(r) sum(Overlap(r, mat))),
               loop = for (i in 1:n) {
                   for (j in 1:n) {
                       a[j] <- Overlap(mat[i, ],mat[j, ])
                   }
                   # Noticed I've moved this sum to the bottom,
                   # so that our first element isn't just a sum from one to n
                   z[i] <- sum(a, na.rm = T)
               })
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#>  apply  7.538967  7.688929  7.894379  7.767989  7.891177  13.57523   100
#>   loop 76.051011 77.203810 80.045325 78.158369 79.206538 114.68139   100
#>  cld
#>   a 
#>    b
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Now let's try to get a sense of how it scales with (slightly) bigger example data (if the data gets too big the benchmarks take forever):

```r
# 
n <- 100
x <- sample(seq(as.Date("2008/10/20"), as.Date("2018/10/20"), "day"), n, r = T)
y <- sample(seq(as.Date("2008/10/20"), as.Date("2018/10/20"), "day"), n, r = T)
mat <- cbind(x, y)
a <- z <- 1:n
for (i in 1:n) {
    for (j in 1:n) {
        a[j] <- Overlap(mat[i, ],mat[j, ])
    }
    z[i] <- sum(a, na.rm = T)
}
# In case you're concerned it still works:
all.equal(z, apply(mat, 1, function(r) sum(Overlap(r, mat))))
#> [1] TRUE
microbenchmark(apply = apply(mat, 1, function(r) sum(Overlap(r, mat))),
               loop = for (i in 1:n) {
                   for (j in 1:n) {
                       a[j] <- Overlap(mat[i, ],mat[j, ])
                   }
                   # Noticed I've moved this sum to the bottom,
                   # so that our first element isn't just a sum from one to n
                   z[i] <- sum(a, na.rm = T)
               })
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#>  apply  258.1151  262.8007  269.8172  265.9643  276.8799  296.2167   100
#>   loop 5806.9834 5841.3362 5890.4988 5863.7317 5884.2308 6222.1670   100
#>  cld
#>   a 
#>    b
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

In Bioinformatics, we use for finding overlapping ranges the `GenomicRanges` packages.

I once also calculated using my usual `for`-loops and `lapply` functions that my computer would calculate 5 days long. But then I found the `GenomicRanges` package - and it did it in seconds!

(Shame on me, I still don't know how it exactly works ... will have to do with ordered tree structure and intersecting efficiently ... and partly also perhaps involving `C++` code? .. )

The result is anyway that it is lightning fast.
You will be amazed!

**GenomicRanges package for lightening fast range calculations**

```
############################
# Install GenomicRanges package
############################

# since this year introduced: `BiocManager`
# Bioconductor is main code repository for Bionformaticians.
# It is kind of `CRAN` for Bioinformaticians programming with R
install.packages("BiocManager")
require(BiocManager) 
BiocManager::install("GenomicRanges")

# In older systems, you have to do:
install.packages("BiocInstaller")
require(BiocInstaller)
biocLite("GenomicRanges")

############################
# Load the GenomicRanges package
############################

require(GenomicRanges)

############################
# create dates as positive intervals
############################

set.seed(123) # for reproducibility of random stuff

n <-  1000 # later: 378742
x <- sample(seq(as.Date("2008/10/20"), as.Date("2038/10/20"), "day"), replace=TRUE, n)
# y <- sapply(x, function(date) date + sample(1:1000, 1)) # too slow!
deltas <- sample(1:10000, replace=TRUE, n) # immediate response `sapply` needs very long
y <- x + deltas

df <- data.frame(seqnames="1", start=x, end=y)
gr <- GRanges(df)
gr <- sort(gr)

############################
# Be careful, GRanges obj is 1-based system and not 0-based!
############################

# each row is one index - gr behaves when indexing like a vector
gr[5]   # selects fifth row
gr[4:7] # selects 4th to 7th row

############################
# which range overlaps with which range?
############################

system.time({hits <- findOverlaps(gr, gr)})   
# system.time({ your-R-expression }) - very convenient speed measuring!
# the numbers in the table are the index (i-th row) in each of the tables
# query and subject table - which are in this case identical tables - gr

############################
# what is the amount of overlap?
############################

overlaps <- pintersect(gr[queryHits(hits)], gr[subjectHits(hits)])
amount.overlaps <- width(overlaps) - 1 # - 1 because 1-based systems do +1 when ranges

# 1-base versus 0-based coordinate systems: https://www.biostars.org/p/84686/
```

Comment: by the way, I tried it with `n=378742` - it is too big ... even with 32Gb RAM and 32Gb Swap memory overflow ... `n=10000` works like a charm, but `n=100000` is heavy. So you have to do it in chunks.

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much! Will try the package.